# Setting permanently variables in windows %username%

Tags: windows, dos

i need to set permanently the %username% variable on windows is that possible?

I mean if I do on command prompt set username=UPPERCASE I can see that the variable is changed, however as expected this does work just in that command prompt, If I open another one the username variable is the original.

I tried to find the correspondent registry value but I did not find it.

I need some automatic way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: There is an application "putty" that takes the username from the enviro.ment, the problem is that for windows the case does not make sense while for other environment it does. So I just want to put a logonscript that change the username to uppercase in any case, even if the user put his username in the lower case.

Comment: Does it have to be USERNAME?  Can it be a different environment variable like `Putty_USERNAME`?

Answer (score 0):

When each process starts, the process gets a copy of the parent process' environment variables.  So, if you used Windows Explorer to start your command prompt.  You get a copy of Explorer.exe's environment variables, but when you edit it in cmd.exe, you don't edit the value for the rest of the system.

That said, Windows provides an event that processes can subscribe to so they can be told that there is a new value for environment variables.  If you are interested, I can try to dig it up.  I've used it before for the Path environment variable and think it may apply to your problem.

Sounds like you should create a bat file. This will prompt the user for their username and put it in the `%USERNAME%` environment variable.

```
SET /p USERNAME=What is your UserName?
putty /user:%username%
```

Comment: I'm very interested in, can you dig? or give me any suggestions? I would really appreciate this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggested another option, though I could not find a way to simply turn the %username% to lower.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=104011 shows how to notify of environment changes.  However, I don't know how to set the username.